# SELECT positions that's still available

Tags: mysql

I'm developing an voting system, and i have a problem of selecting available position based on the limitation per vote on each position.

**tblposition**

```
pos_no      pos_name    limit
1           pres        1
2           vpres       2
3           senator     5
```

**tblcandidates**

```
cand_no     cand_name    cand_pos
1           john         pres
2           kim          vpres
```

therefore :

pres - 0 left

vpres - 1 left

senator - 5 left

Expected positions to be output :

```
 pos_name 
 | vpres    |
 | senator  |
```

but i get wrong output using this statement

```
SELECT pos_name FROM tblposition
WHERE limit > (SELECT COUNT(cand_pos) 
               FROM tblcandidates, tblposition  
               WHERE tblcandidates.cand_pos = tblposition.pos_name)
```

Can anybody help me fix my statement to produce correct output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just a quite different approach to solve this:

```
SELECT 
* 

FROM 
tblposition a 

WHERE
a.limit > (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblcandidates x WHERE x.cand_pos = a.pos_name)
```

This should now work if you spin it!

Feel free to ask if you have any questions.